# Should bin widths of histograms fall on "nice" round numbers?

Tags: statistics, visualization

TLDR - I want to know if it's ok to use bin widths which are not nice round numbers (like integers or simple fractions are)

I have a set of data, for which I have calculated a recommended uniform
bin width using Scott's rule (I'm not interested in non-uniform widths), and the value is a recurring decimal. This means that the bars are placed in awkward positions along the axis, and they do not correspond to the tick marks. Furthermore, it feels a bit awkward to talk about "the data in the range 1.456 - 2.211". What is considered best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In data visualization and statistics, the best practice always depends heavily in the context. For example, if your bins correspond to a biological experiment or your plot is going to be in a newspaper, it is probably enough to consider 1 decimal, nevertheless in physics or mathematics maybe you want to see much more as it may give insight on convergence to certain values.

TLDR: It heavily depends on the context, depending who are you presenting the data to and why you are doing it.

Comment: In this instance, I am creating a sample report. The variable I'm trying to visualise relates to the weight of a set of animals in lbs, i.e. biological.
If I used 1 decimal place (i.e. 0.7) I would end up with bars positioned at unusual positions between tick marks. At this point, would you simply consider using 0.7 increments on the axis?

Comment: I guess in this context the specific number is not so relevant.